# Callonce js function with multiple params from feature file in karate

Tags: spring-boot, karate

If it was just a call I would have done:`* functionName(var1, var2)`

Edit1:

To call a scenario from another scenario with `* callonce` we send a json with all the parameters. For calling a JS function from another scenario also I can send a json with `* callonce`. But was wondering is there a way to do it like `* functionName(var1, var2)` but it should be `callonce`.

Comment: I don't get anything of what you want to ask here. Could you improve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is `call` or `callonce` take a single argument. But - you can wrap the arguments into a single JSON like this:

```
* def data = { var1: '#(var1)', var2: '#(var2)' }
* callonce someFun data
```

Read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#js-function-argument-rules-for-call